# Detect the user's prefered units

Tags: javascript, internationalization, units-of-measurement

How can I detect what units the user prefers to read?

I mean Celcius vs Fahrenheit, meters vs miles, etc.

I can use third-party services like `http://freegeoip.net/json/` to get the IP, country code, etc. I could also use `navigator.language` in the browser to have a hint of the language, but I am not sure if there is a safe way to be sure I present results in the right units to the user.

(Having a select with units options would solve it for the user, but that is not in the scope of my question.)

Comment: Asking them is the only sure way to answer your question. Anything else is a guess that at best is right most of the time, but will be wrong some of the time. For instance, if you prefer metric, and visit the US, your JS guess is wrong.

Comment: @sethflowers that is why I wonder if there is a way via JavaScript to determine exactly what preferences the user has regarding measurement units.

Comment: none that I know of. That would require this preference to be settable somewhere, and that is not a configuration I've ever seen in Windows - don't know about other OS's. Some apps might have this as a preference, but the only one that would matter to your browser would either be your browsers preference, or a preference in the OS, neither of which I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not in Windows or other OS I am aware of. 
Android only started offering ICU (either 4J or C) via its API with the latest "Nougat" release. ICU and Unicode CLDR know several units, but the unit system at the moment is not exposed there either.

If you call an API like http://freegeoip.net/json/, the country name or code would allow you to decide which countries generally adopted the Metric system as opposed to others (only 3 including the US), but there are many countries like e.g. Britain where certain units are also used from the Imperial system. Street signs show the distance in miles while you normally see a gas station offer fuel per litre, not gallon as in the US.